# Can you use a snippet within a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

Like, say I have a snippet:

```
"Script with vue-property-decorator": {
    "prefix": "script",
    "body": [
        "<script lang='ts'>",
        "import {",
        "    Vue,",
        "    Component,",
        "} from 'vue-property-decorator';",
        "",
        "@Component",
        "export default class $1 extends Vue {",
        "",
        "}",
        "</script>",
    ],
},
```

And I want to make a sort of 'meta-snippet' for an entire .vue file -- does VSCode have the capability to call a snippet within another snippet?

I apologize if this has been asked before.  A cursory google search turned up nothing.

My initial solution was just to copy-paste the snippet contents into my new snippet and add onto it.

Comment: How do you mean to combine them?  In one snippet you can type another snippet's prefix into one of its variables and then expand that second snippet inside of the first.  Or you could make a third snippet that used the other two snippets, but in each case you have to trigger (via the snippet prefix) the insertion of the other snippet.  You could also create a macro that combined the two snippets but that is not as flexible as triggering one snippet, which you could choose by prefix, inside another.

Comment: makes sense.  i was mostly just wondering if there was anything built-in supporting it, but it doesn't sound like it.  thanks!